# How to return HRESULT in the .NET's version of IDataObject.SetData()?

Tags: .net, com

'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IDataObject' has

```
public void SetData (ref FORMATETC formatIn, ref STGMEDIUM medium, bool release);
```

, but the IDataObject in `Objidl.h` has

```
HRESULT SetData(
  FORMATETC *pformatetc,
  STGMEDIUM *pmedium,
  BOOL      fRelease
);
```

1. Why is the .NET's version designed to return 'void' instead of a return value?
2. If I want to return a value like `E_INVALIDARG` in the .NET, how can I do so?

Comment: These COM functions get automatically converted, a failure HRESULT generates a corresponding .NET exception.  If you need the value and don't want the exception then the method has to be declared with the [PreserveSig] attribute and a return type of int.  In for example Winforms this is done by not suppressing the exception, since it is helpful, but try/catch-em-all in the drag+drop code.

Comment: That is, I cannot use `System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IDataObject` but have to declare a version myself using `PreserveSig`, right?

Comment: It is pretty much the answer to all of your recent questions, copy/paste from existing .NETCore source and only make changes when you absolutely have to.  You don't have to here, these exceptions are helpful, but you can't get the right help when you don't explain why you need to.